# User Control doesn't display in master page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-4.0

I am working on a old ASP.NET project application.
I have to add a notification menu.

To achieve this, I have created a User Control which contains :

**ComposantNotificationMenu.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ComposantNotificationMenu.ascx.vb" Inherits="extranet.Composant.ComposantNotificationMenu" %>

<ul class="ttw-notification-menu">
    <li id="projects" class="notification-menu-item first-item">
        <a href="#">Mes derniers évènements</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**ComposantNotificationMenu.vb**

```
Namespace Composant

    Public Class ComposantNotificationMenu
        Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Extranet_PageMaitre_Base.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeBehind="Extranet_PageMaitre_Base.master.vb" Inherits="extranet.Extranet_PageMaitre_Base" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="GeneriqueComposant" Namespace="extranet.Composant" Assembly="extranet" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Entete" runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphEntete" runat="server" />
    </head>
    <body <%If Not Me.EstPageAccueil Then%>class="formulaires"<% end if%>>

        <div id="divComposantMenuNotification">
            <GeneriqueComposant:ComposantNotificationMenu ID="ComposantNotificationMenu" runat="server" Visible="true" />
            test
        </div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphCorps" runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The User Control *Load* event is handle but nothing is display on the screen.

I really have no idea.. I already develop other component but never in a master page. Is that the problem ?